# 2 Factor Outlook accounts in OSX Mail?

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have been using a Mac as my primary workstation on a corporate network that is otherwise heavily invested in Microsoft.
Rather than installing Microsoft Office, I have been reading my mail with Apple's "Mail" application by setting up my Exchange Account under Internet Accounts in System Preferences.

However, we have been recently upgraded to Office 365 AND our Exchange accounts have been migrated to "the cloud" AND 2 Factor authentication has been enabled to access said accounts.

This last step appears to have broken my Calendar and Mail apps as OSX's internet accounts doesn't seem to support 2 Factor authentication.

So, given all this, is there any way I can get 2 Factor authentication working so I can continue using Mail.app?

Comment: You would have to have somebody with Administrator control over your Office 365/Exchange talk you through creating an application password for your account.